# Beautifull soup find a tag whith the pressence of an attribute but it's value unknown

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Let say I want to retrieve all tags `p` who got an attribute ID but the value of the attribute is unknown?

```
<p id=?, ... >
```

What is the best way to do it using beautiful soup?

Comment: Just use `soup.find_all('p')`. This way you'll fetch all `<p>` tags, ignoring the `id` tags. Then you can verify if the term "id=" exists at each fetched line.

Comment: How can I check if id exist? Can you write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `soup.find_all('p')`. This way you'll fetch all `<p>` tags, ignoring the `id` attribute.

Then you can verify if the term `"id="` exists in each parsed line.

**Example code:**

```
p_tags = soup.find_all('p')

for item in p_tags:
    if 'id=' in str(item):
        print(item)
    else:
        print("Attr ID not present in this line!")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#true)

check for existance:

```
soup.find_all('p', id=True)
```